# When using an ORM to represent a table, is it wise to have non-table specific functions?

Tags: orm, language-agnostic

For example (not verbatim)

```
/**
@Entity
*/
class Event
{
   /**
      @Column 
   */
   protected $time_start;
   /** .. */
   protected $time_end;

   /** getters, setters, etc */

   /** @return duration of event as a string, non-table function */
   public function getDuration() { ... }
}
```

Or should the ORM just be the table, and nothing more?

This could be a subjective view, as everyone has their own opinions, but in programming there and things you do and things you really shouldn't do. I was just wondering if this is one of those cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not, it is not a good idea. If nothing else, would be violating [*Single responsibility principle*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

If you are making an ORM, your instances should deal only with data storage/retrieval. In your example `getDuration()` is part of domain business logic and should reside within [domain objects](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DomainObject).

Basically, what you are dealing here is the difference between [data mapper](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) and [active record](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) patterns. And, if you are trying to write code that adheres to SOLID principles, one would consider active record to be an antipatter, which in long term causes unmitigated [technical debt](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TechnicalDebt.html).

Comment: Thank you for the response. That makes sense to me, sometimes there is a fine line between doing things right and messing up.

Answer (score 0):

Except if there is some application-specific reasons for not having the function, the answer is a big YES. Let me explain why:

1. In OOP, an object is not just a data structure. It ties state and behavior together. This is a basic principle of OOP. It has a state, and it has methods that modify the state. What is and Entity? It is an object, a business object. Business objects contain business data and logic. As such, they do need to have methods that perform business logic. Removing business logic from business objects is against the essence of OOP. Because, ultimately you will need to implement that logic somewhere, but that will not be the right place. That code will somehow need to access the state of the business object, and that will, in most cases break the principle of Information hiding (Encapsulation) which is one of the reasons why we have OOP in the first place.
2. Now, with regard to ORM! Here you have two needs to fulfill, an object-oriented design and ORM. Now ask which one has the precedence over the other, or, which one comes first. Do you first consider ORM (or any other means for storage) first and then design your classes? Or do you design you classes and then have them mapped/stored? The first method is the right way. You design your application and then let ORM follow from this design.
3. Will non-accessor methods prevent you from having ORM. NO. These methods will not prevent you from having ORM on the object. The designers of ORM frameworks knew about the principle when they designed it.

Comment: What you are suggesting, that one should build domain business logic around the ORM. That's madness.The goal should bot for the ORM and business logic to work independently. If ORM stores a domain object, it should only require for said domain object to implement a specific interface.

Comment: "What you are suggesting, that one should build domain business logic around the ORM". I am saying the exact opposite of that, and giving three reasons for my suggestion. His class (an Entity) is a domain object and therefore it should contain business logic.

Comment: Oh .. nevermind. Looks like the "yes" was answer to the question in the body of post, not the title.

Comment: Yes, I realized later that first sentence of my answer was a bit ambiguous.